# Adding multiple tags in one feature file

Tags: c#, specflow

I have one feature file with different scenarios. Is it a good idea to add multiple tags for each feature file?

```
Feature: Login.

@daily @chrome @admin @smoketest 

Scenario 1

Scenario 2

Scenario 3
```

Will I be able to execute tests using the command line using any one or more than one tag at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, having multiple tags in a feature file is a common use case. You use tags to categorize the tests. Instead of running multiple tags/categories at a time, you can structure your feature file to run all the tests you want by placing the tag the correct place.

Here are two examples:

- Example 1: You have a feature with examples (Scenario Outline). The most common happy path of the feature should be tested every time someone commits (@ci). The less common happy paths should be tested daily (@daily) and the rare paths can be tested weekly (@weekly).

```
Feature: Buy the product
  The product can be bought.

  Scenario Outline: A customer buys the product
    Given product <Product>
      And payment method <PaymentMethod>
     When customer clicks buy
     Then product ends up in basket

    @ci @daily @weekly
    Examples: 
    | Product  | PaymentMethod |
    | Book     | Cash          |

    @daily @weekly
    Examples: 
    | Product  | PaymentMethod |
    | Software | Visa          |
    | Music    | MasterCard    |

    @weekly
    Examples: 
    | Product  | PaymentMethod |
    | Watch    | DinersClub    |
    | Hitman   | BitCoin       |
```

I could now set up my CI/CD tool to run

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=ci
```

every time someone commit. I could schedule this

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=daily
```

to runs once per day. And finally I could set up this to run weekly:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=weekly
```

Notice that the daily category also will run the ci test, and the weekly category will run all tests, because the tags are there too. So the ci test is a superficial but fast test, while the weekly is the most thorough test because it runs all the scenarios.

- Example 2: You have a feature that fulfills several requirements. Some scenarios can be used to test several requirements at a time.

```
Feature: Start and stop engine
  The engine has a start/stop mechanism that can be triggered by software.

  @req123 @req124
  Scenario: Start engine
    Given engine is stopped
     When operator clicks on start button
     Then engine starts

  @req123 @req124
  Scenario: Stop engine
    Given engine is started
     When operator clicks on stop button
     Then engine starts

  @req123
  Scenario: Start engine
    Given engine is stopped
     When operator clicks on stop button
     Then nothing happens
```

If we wanted to prove requirement 123 we would run:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=req123
```

And all the scenarios would run. If we wanted to prove requirement 124 we would run

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=req124
```

And the two first scenarios would run. The last would be skipped because it wasn't tagged with req124.